# R: plot a discrete uniform distribution with wide bars

Tags: r

I have the following R code:

```
library(extraDistr)

x <- rdunif(100, 1, 6)
barplot(x, xlab="x", ylab="P(X=x)", ylim=c(0, 0.2))
```

It generates a plot that looks like this:

[image]

But I want a plot that looks like this (but with bars that have equal height (all 1/6), and xlim=c(1, 6)):

[image]

How can I make the graph I'm looking for?

Comment: Stick a `table` in there. `barplot(table(x), ...)`

Comment: I think you want something more like `barplot(table(x)/length(x), xlab="x", ylab="P(X=x)", ylim=c(0, 0.2))` `barplot` will not summarize your data for you. You need to do it yourself with `table()` which gives counts, and if your proportions you need to divide by the total number of observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do `barplot(prop.table(table(x)))`

Comment: @d.b `hist` is for a continuous variable.

Comment: Ended up using:

library(extraDistr)

x <- rdunif(1e6, 1, 6)
par(mar=c(5,6,4,1)+.1)
barplot(table(x)/1e6, xlab="x", ylab="P(X=x)", ylim=c(0, 0.2), xlab="x")

Comment: @StatsSorceress it is exactly the same thing